# ASP.NET MVC3: Get method only accessible through other method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, registration

I'm using the standard forms authentication registration that comes with MVC 3.
I want to add a few checkboxes to that form that indicates what kind of user the registrator will be. Depending on the checkbox choice the user will be redirected to another get method where additional information can be added.

The problem is that I don't want these methods to be accessible in any other way (like typing the url for example). Only in this specific case these these methods can be accessed.

My first idea was to create a session in the post method of the first registration form and check in the get method if the session exists. But this seems like a less elegant way.

Does anyone has a safer solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [ChildActionOnly] attribute: [found here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute.aspx).